# how to check if field is autoincrement or not in symfony2 using doctrine2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am getting type of field using classMedataData using below,

```
$em->getClassMetadata('AcmeDemoBundle:' . $entityName)->getTypeOfField($fieldName)),
```

I want to check if the field is autoincrement or not. I tried using this,

```
$em->getClassMetadata('AcmeDemoBundle:' . $entityName)->isIdentifier($fieldName)),
```

but it doesnt give whether it is autoincrement or not ? Basically I want

```
   generator: { strategy: AUTO }
```

metadata from entity name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is stored in "generatorType" public MetadataInfo class property
To get it, use:

```
$em->getClassMetadata('AcmeDemoBundleBundle:'.$entityName)->generatorType;
```

generator_type constants are defined as is:

```
const GENERATOR_TYPE_AUTO = 1;
const GENERATOR_TYPE_SEQUENCE = 2;
const GENERATOR_TYPE_TABLE = 3;
const GENERATOR_TYPE_IDENTITY = 4;
const GENERATOR_TYPE_NONE = 5;
const GENERATOR_TYPE_UUID = 6;
const GENERATOR_TYPE_CUSTOM = 7;
```

Comment: Thanks, which value relates to  auto increment primory key id column ?  Looks obvious GENERATOR_TYPE_AUTO but I am getting GENERATOR_TYPE_IDENTITY for entities which has generator: { strategy: AUTO }

Comment: I was trying $em->getMetadataFactory()->getMetadataFor('AcmeDemoBundle:' . $entityname)->idGenerator

Answer (score 0):

Late-answering to @vishal's question, about what type to use for the auto-increment - the GENERATOR_TYPE_IDENTITY is actually the correct one (see below).

Excerpt from Symfony v3.3 code, *ClassMetaDataInfo.php*:

```
/* The Id generator types. */
/**
 * AUTO means the generator type will depend on what the used platform prefers.
 * Offers full portability.
 */
const GENERATOR_TYPE_AUTO = 1;

/**
 * SEQUENCE means a separate sequence object will be used. Platforms that do
 * not have native sequence support may emulate it. Full portability is currently
 * not guaranteed.
 */
const GENERATOR_TYPE_SEQUENCE = 2;

/**
 * TABLE means a separate table is used for id generation.
 * Offers full portability.
 */
const GENERATOR_TYPE_TABLE = 3;

/**
 * IDENTITY means an identity column is used for id generation. The database
 * will fill in the id column on insertion. Platforms that do not support
 * native identity columns may emulate them. Full portability is currently
 * not guaranteed.
 */
const GENERATOR_TYPE_IDENTITY = 4;

/**
 * NONE means the class does not have a generated id. That means the class
 * must have a natural, manually assigned id.
 */
const GENERATOR_TYPE_NONE = 5;

/**
 * UUID means that a UUID/GUID expression is used for id generation. Full
 * portability is currently not guaranteed.
 */
const GENERATOR_TYPE_UUID = 6;

/**
 * CUSTOM means that customer will use own ID generator that supposedly work
 */
const GENERATOR_TYPE_CUSTOM = 7;
```

So, you may use some function like this:

```
public function isPrimaryKeyAutoGenerated(): bool
{
    return $this->classMetaData && $this->classMetaData->generatorType == ClassMetadataInfo::GENERATOR_TYPE_IDENTITY;
}
```